# Invalid Options Argument when creating react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation

So I have been trying to learn how to write a react webpage and I am currently just trying to create a react app. I have been trying to use the command `npx create-react-app {project name}` but it keeps saying that it has an Invalid options argument. I have tried `npm -g uninstall create-react-app` and clearing the cache and reinstalling the package but it has the same error.

**Error message for npx:**
[image]

**Error message for npm install:**
[image]

I'm wondering what is wrong with my command. Please help!

***Edit***
Someone in the comment has asked me to try updating my npm with 'npm install -g npm@latest' and for whatever reason, I got the same error message again! (Hoping that this might give a better picture of my error.) Thanks for the thought tho.

Also, my node js version is v16.13.0 and npm is 8.1.0

**Picture for my windows path variable:**
[image]

**Error Log when running npx create-react-app:**
[image]

Comment: Maybe try to update npm to latest version via `npm install -g npm@latest`

Comment: I dont know why I just tried that and I am getting the same error

Comment: Are u trying on linux/windows/linux subsystem for windows ?
If windows maybe try to install LTS version of node from nodejs.org

Comment: I am using windows and yup I downloaded the LTS version of node before I did all these stuff :(.

Comment: `npm -v` and `node -v` works correctly ? Maybe you have corrupted windows path env variable

Comment: yup npm -v and node -v worked correctly how may I check if the windows path env is corrupted? I have uploaded my windows path variable in the question please help me take a look. Thanks for helping man